# PHP/MySQL Data Limit

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to limit the amount of data displayed by MySQL & PHP I have a java plugin for Minecraft that logs user logins into a table on MySQL, The data is inserted into the database with:

"Username" "joindate" "exitdate"

"NAME" "DATE at TIME" "DATE at TIME"

I want to limit the data so I don't get duplicates after the Joindate is exploded and the "at (TIME)" is removed.

Currently how it shows is: 3/03/2013 | 3/03/2013 | 3/03/2013 I want to be able to hide these one's so there's not hundreds of extra's that doesn't need to be there

Comment: do you want to get the latest date for each `name`?

Comment: well while i have no idea what your asking it does look like your not using the db's date\time formats, but storing a date as text?

Comment: share the query which displays duplicates and expected result.

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logging") {  =P

Comment: Here's the code:

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logging") { 

The data is inserted like this:

id  username  joindate  exitdate
13  NoMansLand_MFGC 26-02-2013 at 03:55:26 26-02-2013 at 03:58:16
14  NoMansLand_MFGC 26-02-2013 at 04:10:11 26-02-2013 at 04:24:27

Answer (score 0):

Try `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`Joindate`,'%y%m%d')
```

If it's not a native DATE type column you could try substring so long as your dates are standard in length:

```
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`Joindate`,0,9)
```

This will bring all matches into one result.